# Upload files to Sharepoint document libraries via FTP

Tags: sharepoint, upload, ftp

I was wondering if anyone knows how to or if it is possible to upload files to a sharepoint (v3/MOSS) document library over FTP.  I know it is possible with webdav.  If it is possible is this even supported by Microsoft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so. I think your options are:

1. HTTP (via the upload page)
2. WebDAV
3. Web Services
4. The object model

Comment: Doesn't the stuff you upload gets saved in the database, not the file system, so FTP wouldn't know where to put it?

Comment: The files are saved in BLOB fields in the Content database, but if webdav works (through windows explorer, why wouldn't ftp?)

Answer (score 3):

You can map a drive to a SharePoint document library, for example \\serveraddress.domain.com\Documents. So I would try mapping a drive on your FTP server, then making sure files that come in over FTP get sent to that drive.

Comment: For some strange reason mapping from explorer didn't work for me. Instead, the following worked well (once you're not copying from a non-windows machine)...
* Open dos cmd prompt.
* Create a mapped drive by using "net use DriveLetter: \\path\to\sharepoint\site"

Copy at will or from a script, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Big edit: Have any of you figured out how to upload to SharePoint (WSS)? I've tried drive mapping and then using [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) and Synctoy to copy files thinking a tool might offer greater control (i.e. a **Copy Date Modified** control).  As I understand it the files are actually stored in SharePoint as database objects and therefore SharePoint views display the database object (SQL object's) properties in Document Libraries where a new user would expect to see the file properties.  Those file properties are still alive!  They just need to be uncovered by a different view. I particularly like the mapped network drive view of a SharePoint Document Library. File attributes are pretty important to my team, so we were concerned about that at the start.  As an opinion note though, the default view showing attributes that appear as incorrect is just plain annoying!

The **best** solution we've come up with for doing large file migrations into SharePoint is a mapped network drive then using a tool called [FreeFileSync available at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) to move your files and folders.  It's great because it produces verbose error messages and give a lot of control, especially for the instances that SharePoint tries to block a particular filename or file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Direct FTP into SharePoint is not one of your options.  You would need to have a timer job run that checks your FTP directory and uploads into the document library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

The WebDav Redirector allows you to access webdav resources (including Share Point) via UNC path, ie \yourspserver\site\doclib.  The IIS FTP server accepts UNC paths as backing storage to virtual directories.

On your ftp server, right click the ftp site in the IIS Manager and select "Add Virtual Directory".  Give it a name and specify the sharepoint unc path for the physical path.  You'll need to set the "connect as" user to a domain user that has access to the sharepoint folder you're connecting to.

Connect to the ftp folder and you should be able to "cd" into the directory and put/get files without issue (just confirmed it myself).  The only caveat is an age old bug/feature of IISFTP, that doesn't show a virtual dir in an ls/dir command listing.  The fix is to create a physical folder that mirrors the virtual directory's location.  For example, if your ftp root is c:\inetpub\ftproot, then you'll need to create a dir that matches the name of your virtual dir in this location.  It will then show up in an ls/dir listing but the cd command will still move into the virtual dir, not the physical dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly SFTP/FTP into your SharePoint doc library using [Couchdrop](http://couchdrop.io). It turns your SharePoint into a native SFTP/FTP server, you can create additional users, etc. Sing out if you need assistance more than happy to assist.

Full disclosure: I represent Couchdrop